# PyDev Jython module_not_found_in_the_pythonpath, autocomplete not working

Tags: java, pydev, jython, pythonpath

I've been searching for two days now trying to get PyDev to recognize my external .JAR (It's obfuscated for protection), however no matter what I do it doesn't want to work. I've read over the documentation for nearly a hour straight trying to get it to work.

I'm helping to work on an emulation server which uses Jython for scripting. I can compile and run the emulation server with the scripts working just fine however, without using autocompletion for the methods inside the engine part of the server which is obfuscated in a external .jar. 
Here is an example code of a script which uses methods from the obfuscated .JAR (which isn't working with autocomplete, so I have to navigate through the package explorer to find the method I want to use):

```
import sys

def CreateStartingCharacter(core, object):

testObject = core.objectService.createObject('object/weapon/ranged/rifle/shared_rifle_t21.iff', object.getPlanet())
testObject.setCustomName('This is a Jython Rifle')
testObject.setStringAttribute('crafter', 'Light')
inventory = object.getSlottedObject('inventory')
inventory.add(testObject)

testClothing = core.objectService.createObject('object/tangible/wearables/cape/shared_cape_rebel_01.iff', object.getPlanet())
testClothing.setCustomName('Test Cape')
testCloak = core.objectService.createObject('object/tangible/wearables/robe/shared_robe_jedi_dark_s05.iff', object.getPlanet())
testCloak.setCustomName('Test Cloak')

inventory.add(testClothing)
inventory.add(testCloak)

return
```

This script is executed by the following command in Java (core is the class inside the external JAR, obfuscated)
`core.scriptService.callScript("scripts/", "demo", "CreateStartingCharacter", object);`

object is...
`CreatureObject object = (CreatureObject)core.objectService.createObject(sharedRaceTemplate, core.terrainService.getPlanetList().get(0));`

Like I said above, all of those methods that I used in the script were from the obfuscated JAR which isn't working with autocomplete. However, I can use a method that isn't in that JAR just fine such as:

```
from resources.common import RadialOptions
from services.sui import SUIWindow
from services.sui.SUIWindow import Trigger
from java.util import Vector
import sys

def createRadial(core, owner, target, radials):
radials.clear()
bank = owner.getSlottedObject('bank')
if bank:
    radials.add(RadialOptions(0, 21, 1, ''))
    radials.add(RadialOptions(0, 7, 1, ''))
    radials.add(RadialOptions(1, RadialOptions.bankTransfer, 3, '@sui:bank_credits'))
    radials.add(RadialOptions(1, RadialOptions.bankitems, 3, '@sui:bank_items'))    
    if owner.getBankCredits() > 0:
        radials.add(RadialOptions(1, RadialOptions.bankWithdrawAll, 3, '@sui:bank_withdrawall'))
    if owner.getCashCredits() > 0:
        radials.add(RadialOptions(1, RadialOptions.bankDepositAll, 3, '@sui:bank_depositall'))

return
```

... and using RadialOptions. control+space will show me all the methods.

Help would be much appreciated. At this point I feel that it's not working because the JAR file is obfuscated or something like that. And yes, I've already added it to my PYTHONPATH and updated the interpreter, just like with the bin folder for my project.